# Notation of a dynamically changing set

Tags: notation

If there is a set D=[2,4,7,8,11] each represent a possible distance to a point. After some time t, the distance t * 2 is subtracted from every element in A. For example, after 2 minutes we subtract 4 from every element so the new A will become:
The new D=[-2,0,3,4].
Say that we want to remove every element that is $\le$  0 so it becomes : D=[3,4]

My question is what is the best and formal way to write that? 
I don’t wanna keep saying the new D.
Should I say $D_i$ (where i is the passed time)? What about before and after removing the elements that are <= 0?

Comment: This is unintelligible because you haven't explained what "A" might be and the example doesn't seem to conform to the process of subtraction.

Comment: This is the second time you close my question. I did my best. I used an example. what else do you want?